# Is it possible to target the very last list element in CSS?

Tags: css, html-lists

I have a page menu being generated that will be similar in structure to the following nested list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>
        Page 3
        <ul>
            <li>Subpage 1</li>
            <li>Subpage 2</li> <!-- Can I target ONLY this element? -->
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Note that this list is dynamic. **The number of items and number of levels are not predictable**. So, something like this wouldn't be flexible enough:

```
/* I know this does not have great browser support - just an example */
ul > li > ul > li:last-child {
    /* CSS here */
}
```

I realize that I could modify my server code to add a class to the last item, but I would first like to know if this is possible in CSS.

To make matters more complicated, I would like to target all major browsers along with IE 7+.

**Is it possible to target the very last list item using CSS?**

Basically, I need this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NaJas/) solved (via @Pumbaa80).

Comment: People seem to have a hard time understanding your question. I put up a JSFiddle to illustrate the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/NaJas/

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Thanks. I'll edit my question to include that fiddle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### The CSS3 Way (IE9+)

If you know exactly how deep your last item is, you can repeat your calls to `:last-child`:

```
li:last-child li:last-child {
    color: red;
}
```

This pseudo-class selector isn't supported in IE prior to version 9, according to http://caniuse.com/#search=last-child. Of course, if you don't know how deep this list item will be, then this method isn't really helpful.

#### The JavaScript Way

You can target the very last list item via JavaScript as well:

```
var items = document.getElementById("mylist").getElementsByTagName("li"),
    _item = items[ items.length - 1 ];

_item.className == "" 
  ? _item.className = "last" 
  : _item.className += " last" ;
```

This is raw JavaScript, which requires no additional frameworks or libraries. If you're using a popular framework like jQuery, this could be even simpler:

```
$("#mylist li:last").addClass("last");
```

I wouldn't suggest you use jQuery *just* for something like this. Raw JavaScript would be far faster, and far less bloat.

#### The Preprocessor way

Depending on how your navigational menu is constructed, you may be able to use a server-side language to identify the last list-item, and mark it as such. For example, we could perform the following using the `DOMDocument` class in PHP:

```
$d = new DOMDocument();
$d->loadHTML( $html );
    
$a = $d->getElementsByTagName("li");
$l = $a->item( $a->length - 1 );

$c = $l->getAttribute("class");

empty( $c ) 
  ? $l->setAttribute("class", "last") 
  : $l->setAttribute("class", "last $c");

echo $d->saveHTML( $l );
```

This finds the last list item in the HTML and adds a new class of "last" to it. The benefit to this is that it doesn't require complicated, and often times poorly-supported, CSS3 selectors. Further, it doesn't require the addition of large JavaScript libraries to do trivial things.

Comment: This won't be flexible enough. I updated my question to include a Fiddle example.

Comment: @Steve You really shouldn't load into a 37kb library just for something like this. The solutions above are indeed flexible enough, and I'm currently working on a preprocessing example that would work 100% of the time.

Comment: Sorry, I meant your CSS solution wasn't flexible enough (I simply don't know the number of nested levels that could be there - may need `li:last-child li:last-child li:last-child`). Your other solutions would work (I think).

Comment: @Steve I understand. I'll continue with my last solution as it may contribute to your options.

Answer (score 5):

You posted the correct way:

```
li:last-child
```

If you need to be sure you can use javascript / jQuery to do it. But then you could have the problem: "if people have js disabled?"... no way.

Use `li:last-child`.

---

Edit:

If you can add atleast a class on the `UL` will be easy.
Otherwise if you are sure to have only two list:

```
ul ul li:last-child { /* code */ }
```

---

Another Edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/4NXg2/

Double solution, js and css.

---

Edit again:

Your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/toroncino/NaJas/1/

```
$('ul').last().addClass('last');​
```

Comment: Sure, I answered that there isn't any way.. or the css:last-child or javascript solutions... there is nothing for old browsers or for javascript disabled browsers...

Comment: I meant that I need ONLY the very last li element, not simply the last li element of the outer most nested level. With that in mind, `li:last-child` doesn't work for me (http://jsfiddle.net/h3Zzm/).

Comment: @Steve Can you add classes on UL? I improved my answer.

Comment: @Steve improved again with a jsFiddle.

Comment: This still isn't flexible enough for what I need accomplished. I added an example Fiddle for what I need done. (I don't know how many nested list levels I could have).

Comment: Take a look at my Fiddle than.

Comment: @AndreaTurri Thanks, your fiddle does work now. Of course, if I were going to use JavaScript, I'd eliminate the need for `:last-child` (bad browser support) at all. Something like: `$('ul').last().children().last().addClass('last');​` I'll see if anybody posts a pure CSS solution. If not, I'll accept your answer.

Comment: doesn't exist a pure css solution... sorry. I already had this trouble in past... no solution except js.

Comment: @AndreaTurri There are other solutions than just JavaScript. You could process the data on the server prior to printing it, as I showed in my third example.

Answer (score 1):

In short : no. The constraints you're giving make CSS solutions impractical due to the (very) poor support for 'advanced css' in IE7.

Would the use of javascript be an option in your case? With jquery the following comes to mind:

```
$('ul li').last().css('color', 'red');
```

edit:
This will also bypass your 'unknown tree depth' issue as child nodes of the last li would automatically be further down in the list of matching items but child nodes of earlier li items would not :

- 1st element
- 2nd element
- 3rd element

  - 4th element
- 5th element

edit: i've updated your fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/NaJas/4/

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. Your constraint

> The number of items and number of levels are not predictable.

means that CSS2 selectors, and even CSS3 selectors are not sufficient:

Suppose you have a selector that works for list depth 2. Now adding a third list level in that item would have to invalidate that selector, i.e. the selector would have to depend on the element's child elements. Selectors like that don't exist yet and [will be introduced in CSS4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject), where this would be a solution to your problem:

```
/* CSS4 */
li:last-child:not($li li) {
    /**/
}
```

The selector `$li li` means "an `li` that has some `li` descendant".

Answer (score 0):

You can use li:last-child in your CSS