# JavaScript - Find a specific DOM element with array syntax and update it

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, css-selectors

I would like know if it's possible to find a specific element in my DOM with those constraints:

- Elements have not **id**, you have to follow a specific order (childs in childs).
- Easy syntax (ex: a css selector syntax for arrays)
- *Optional but preferred*: Native JS (vanilla)

Example:

```
<body>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>TEXT TO UPDATE</div>
        </div>
    <div>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

I would like to do something like that:

```
document.querySelector('body > div[2] > div[0] > div[0]').innerHTML = 'UPDATED';
```

If my constraints are too strong, do you have an alternative solution with jQuery ?

EDIT: Thanks to [Rajaprabhu Aravindasamy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1209018/rajaprabhu-aravindasamy), solution is:

```
document.querySelector("body > div:nth-child(3) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)").innerHTML = 'UPDATED';
```

Comment: `document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(3) div').innerHTML = 'UPDATED';`

Comment: What you've shown has **only** `div` elements. Is it true in your actual data? (It's relevant.)

Comment: This might help I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415016/is-it-possible-to-target-the-very-last-list-element-in-css

Comment: As @RajaprabhuAravindasamy has suggested, the answer is the [nth-child selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child). Note that `n` is 1-based rather than 0-based however.

Comment: `document.querySelector("div > div").innerHTML = "UPDATED"`; will work in your example. But, I suspect that your example is not as clear as your question is asking about.

Comment: So the direct translation of your proposed selector (that doesn't appear to correspond to your actual HTML anyway) would look like: `document.querySelector('body > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1)')`

Answer (score 0):

You partially provided your answer in your question since you seem to know about `document.querySelector()`. What you need is a transformation function to convert your custom selector into a CSS selector.

```
function customSel2cssSel(sel) {
    // match a nodeType followed by index brackets, use a replace function
    // to replace both grouped tokens by the CSS selector pendant
    return sel.replace(/([a-z]+)\[([0-9]+)\]/g, function(repl, nodeName, nodeIndex){
        return nodeName + ":nth-child(" + (Number(nodeIndex) + 1) + ")";
    });
}
```

I'd say your example contains an error - the DOM and the selector do not match.

```
<body>
<div>dont update</div>
    <div>dont update</div>
    <div>
        <div><div>dont update</div></div>
        <div><span>TEXT TO UPDATE</span></div>
        <div><div>dont update</div></div>
    </div>
<div>dont update</div>
</body>
```

The above DOM would perfectly work with this selector:

```
document.querySelector(customSel2cssSel("body > div[2] > div[1] > span[0]"))
> <span>TEXT TO UPDATE</span>
```

---

If your question's DOM and pseudo code have no error I'd appreciate if you clarify them.